# Finding context in a sentence

Tags: nlp, nltk

I have a problem where given a list of contexts (words), and given a sentense (that could containt a word that is exactly like one of the words in the context or the word in another tense or form or written in another manner,
Is there a way to retrieve, using NLTK maybe, the context from the sentense?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

As a very basic method, you could stem the words and look for them in the sentence.
In the example below, I'm looking for the word `eating` in the sentence, but because I stem the words before matching, it will match words like `eat`, `eats`, etc.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer                                                                      

stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")

key_word = stemmer.stem("eating")

for word in "He eats bread . I eat cake . Are you eating ?".split():
    if stemmer.stem(word) == key_word:
        print(word)
```

You mention tense, but this simplistic approach won't work for words like `ate`, since `eat` and `ate` don't have a common stem.